# How can I programmatically detect if a site prohibits screen scraping?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I've written a small program that find all links on a web page and dumps them into a list, then loops through that list, opens each link and collects all links on those pages. It does this n layers deep.

I'm using Beautiful Soup to screen scrape. One of the problems I've run into is that some pages don't allow screen scraping and crash the program. I've written a snippet of code that detects if a site doesn't allow scraping by looking for if the title tag of the page says "Access Denied". Sites that have this use CloudFare to block screen scraping.

```
>     links = []
>     for link in links:
>             if not nltk.clean_html(str(connect_to_webpage(link).find_all('title')))[2:15]
> == 'Access denied': #check link title tag to see if site says 'Access Denied'
>                 links.append(link)
```

Apparently not everyone uses Cloud Fare though, so there are some instances it doesn't catch and the program crashes. Is there a universal condition I can add that will catch all instances of screen scraper blocking? What is the best way to go about this? Thanks.

Comment: For starters, are you obeying [robots.txt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard)?

Comment: You should also probably be looking at the [HTTP status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) and only try to parse `2xx` responses.

Comment: "some pages don't allow screen scraping and crash the program" - how the crap would they do that?

Comment: What is "Cloud Fare"?  Or do you mean [`Cloudflare`](https://www.cloudflare.com/),

Comment: Cloudflare is what I meant. The error I get is: raise IOError, ('http error', errcode, errmsg, headers)
IOError: ('http error', 401, 'Unauthorized', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x10f2d4248>)

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your User agent,

```
req = urllib.request.Request(url, None,headers={'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'})
```